# How do I use OOP with restful api service?

Tags: rest, oop

I have the following example, which I don't know how to solve.

REST endpoint is

```
DELETE /shop/:shopId/order/:orderId
```

When I am using OOP to consume this rest api service I create Shop and Order models.

```
class Shop {
  order: Order[]
}

class Order {
  id: string
  amount: number

  delete() {}
}
```

I want to call method delete, when I delete an order, but order does not have access to shopId so I can't invoke method. How do I solve this issue?

```
order.delete()
```

What I have to is add method to delete order into shop.

```
shop.deleteOrder(orderId)
```

The problem is when a lot of resources belong to shop. In this case shop becomes bloated as everything needs to pass through it. What is solution?

```
METHOD /resource/:resourceId/subResource/:subResourceId

class Resource {
  subResource: SubResource[]
}

class SubResource {
  method() {}
}
```

Comment: Why can't order have `shopId`? Why is it needed for deletion?

Comment: API is external, I do not control it. When I receive list of orders using GET /shop/:shopId/order they do not contain shopId. Should I use adapter pattern to include shopId in each order?